# How to return a value from a HTTP response callback function in c++ (UE5.2)

Tags: c++, http, unreal-engine5

I am trying to send a HTTP request in c++ with Unreal Engine 5.2 as part of a function, using HttpModule.h and I have a lambda function to handle the response from the request, which works itself. But from the main function I want to return whether the response was successful (i.e. I was able to get an access code in the response data). Here's a simplification of my code:

```
TPromise<bool> Success;
Request->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindLambda(
    [&](
        FHttpRequestPtr Request,
        FHttpResponsePtr Response,
        bool ConnectedSuccessfully) mutable
    {
        if (ConnectedSuccessfully)
        {
            Success.SetValue(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Success.SetValue(false);
        }
    }
);
Request->ProcessRequest();

return Success.GetFuture().Get();
```

I tried using just a bool and updating it in the lambda function and returning it at the end and you can see I also tried to use a TPromise and update it in the lambda function, but this causes unreal to freeze and do nothing.

How can I return whether the response was successful or not?

Comment: `Request->ProcessRequest();` can return `false`, and you don't check it.

Comment: So you would suggest doing:
`
if (Request->ProcessRequest()) {
    return Success.GetFuture.Get();
} else {
    return false;
}`?

Comment: Avoid using if-else. `if (ConnectedSuccessfully)
        {
            Success.SetValue(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Success.SetValue(false);
        }` can be just `Success.SetValue(ConnectedSuccessfully);`. `Request->ProcessRequest();` should be `if (!Request->ProcessRequest();) return false;`.